# Error with relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a `User` table and an `Avatar` table. One User can have many avatars (or null). But I need to mark which avatar is the current, so I have an `Avatar_Id` in User table that is the current avatar. And a ForeignKey `User_Id` in Avatar to tell me which User is the owner.

Trying to do that is generating me a lot of errors and headaches when I try to populate some data in order to test the relationship.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Avatar Avatar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Avatar> Avatars { get; set; }
}

public class Avatar
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Test part:

```
var user = new User();
var avatar = new Avatar()
{
    User = user
};
// user.Avatar = avatar; // <- this gives [a circular] error; without this I have null.
db.Users.Add(user);
db.Avatars.Add(avatar);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This is resulting me with `Avatar_Id = NULL` within `User` table, and `User_Id = NULL` in `Avatar` table. I expected these fields filled (well, `Avatar_Id` can be null).

Comment: I think the first error lies in concept of you try to do. What you really want? You need to think that exists a DDL SQL in background of any Code First code, but I can't see here what (DDL SQL) you expect to get.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi: basicaly I want that an User can have zero or many avatars and to know which avatar is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to make boolean field 'IsDefault' in table with avatar and check while add/update avatars that no more default avatars for this user. Also you can add same property in avatar class.

Answer (score 1):

@Fabricio I can't test this code before post, but I'm pretty convinced it will work.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int AvatarId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AvatarId")]
    public Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Avatar> Avatars { get; set; }
}

public class Avatar
{
    [Key]
    public int AvatarId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when you put two foreign keys merge like one. Now you have a foreign key in Avatar table and other in User table, each one represents one mode of relationship.
The foreign key `"AvatarId"` represents a special form of foreign key, a unique + foreign key, (a second form to build the one to one relationship). You can read more about this in here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Comment: The primary Key of User and Avatar need to be `UserId` and `AvatarId`? cannot be just `Id`?

Comment: Yes you can change for any name you want. But it's a good practice have a more specific name for a primary key. When you change the names pay attention to the `AvatarId` and `[ForeignKey("AvatarId")]` in the `User` class, they need has the same name. If this your correct answer remember up vote and set as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've given this a bit of though because I modeled a similar case once and didn't mind to reevaluate the options.

Look closely at your premises:

> One User can have many avatars (or null)

This short sentence implies that the one-to-one association `User-Avatar` must be optional both ways, because a `User` *without* `Avatar`s can’t possibly refer to one its own avatars, and when a user has more than one avatar *only one of them* can refer to `User` as being the user's default. (They all refer to user as owner).

So you can only model it as a 0..1 – 0..1 association. So `Avatar`’s primary key can't be a foreign key to user. (It couldn't anyway, otherwise a user could only have one avatar).

Maybe this could have been done by Jonny Piazzi's model if this wouldn't throw the infamous "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" exception. Both user and Avatar refer to one another and you have to tell EF explicitly which of the FKs is not cascading. This can only be done by fluent mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
      .HasOptional(u => u.Avatar)
      .WithOptionalDependent()
      .Map(m => m.MapKey("AvatarId"))
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    ...
}
```

This puts a nullable, non-cascading FK column `AvatarId` in User (that's why `User` is the dependent of `Avatar`).

---

Now your second issue, the chicken-eg problem when populating the model.

This can only be done when you call `SaveChanges` twice and wrap these calls in a transaction scope. For example:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    var user = new User();
    var avatar = new Avatar();
    user.Avatars = new HashSet<Avatar>();
    user.Avatars.Add(avatar);
    user.Avatars.Add(new Avatar());
    user.Avatars.Add(new Avatar());
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    user.Avatar = avatar; // set FK
    db.SaveChanges();
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Now EF can decide which key to generate first (`User`'s) before referring to it by foreign keys. Subsequently you set the FK in `User`.

**But... is this the best model?**

Maybe, maybe not.

The issue is that your model does not enforce the business rule that a user can only have one of its own avatars as default avatar. `User.AvatarId` can refer to *any* avatar. So you have to write business logic to enforce the business rule.

With YD1m's solution (no `User.AvatarId`, but a column `Avatar.IsDefault`) this business rule is enforced implicitly. But now you have to write business logic to enforce that only one avatar is the default.

It's up to you to decide what you think is more feasible.

(for the record: way back, I took the latter option)